# Filtering rows in NSPredicate by comparing 2 dates within the row

Tags: nspredicate, nsdatecomponents

Records in my database contain 2 NSDate fields.
At creation of the record both date fields are identical.
Using the app moves one of the two date fields to current time of day.
I want to construct an NSPredicate clause that will only return rows where Date1 is younger than Date2.
All the examples I've seen so far compare dates to externally supplied values as in:
" > %@", refDate

What I'm after is the construction that equates to: 
"[Date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:Date1] > 0.0". Naturally, this won't work.

Any help or pointers to existing examples will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

OK! I need therapy! I can use a block to execute exactly the predicate condition that I highlighted in my original question! Consider this one closed!